# ruby array element grouping

Tags: ruby, arrays, element, grouping

here is the problem

I have an array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and want to get:

```
b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

what is the best way? thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like you're already done!

Comment: what about [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: Are you asking someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: what have you tried? and what would be the expected output there? do you want all 7 element groups? all 3 element groups? Ask the question better and you'll get answers better than my snark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for all unique sets of 3 elements out of a set of 4.

Use Array#combination method:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a.combination(3).to_a
```

output:

```
=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

More info:

[Array#combination](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-combination)
[Wikipedia Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my first implementation. (But performance suckz i guess)

```
array = [1,2,­3,4]
b = []
array.each­{|e| c = array­.clone; c.del­ete(e); b << c}
# b.sort!
```