# Get k-1 length subset arrays of k length array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby array element grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674010/ruby-array-element-grouping)

Example. Given array a:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Its length is 3 so I want to print all 2-length arrays. These are:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
```

I don't know if there is some method in Ruby to get subset arrays. If there is not such a method what is most efficient way to do achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just a simple [combination](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-combination) of 2 elements:

```
 >> xs = [1, 2, 3]
 >> xs.combination(xs.size - 1).to_a
 => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

[EDIT] As @Joshua pointed out in a comment, the docs state that the order is not guaranteed (!). So here is a functional implementation that generates the combinations in the order you asked for. For completeness, I'll make it lazy as the original `combination` method:

```
require 'enumerable/lazy'

class Array
  def combinations_of(n)
    if n == 0
      [[]].lazy
    else
      0.upto(self.size - 1).lazy.flat_map do |idx|
        self.drop(idx + 1).combinations_of(n - 1).map do |xs| 
          [self[idx]] + xs
        end
      end    
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, but docs say _["The implementation makes no guarantees about the order in which the combinations are yielded"](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:combination)_ might be a problem for OP.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: I admit I am baffled by this warning...